# Cannnot copy the contents from my website

Tags: wordpress

This question may seem a little bit not normal. I am sorry if it does. Please consider this. But i spent my time to find the solution for this but I couldn't find a relevant one. So I ended up to think of asking it here.

I just created a website using the candidate theme of wordpress. Everything was fine with it. But now i find that the contents of the site are not copyable. The site doesn't allow the contents even to select them.
I don't know what is preventing this from. What can the problem be? And how can this be disabled? Anyone can give me ideas on this? As for the site, we want to allow any users to select and copy the contents i.e. the articles from the site.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you turn off JavaScript, can text be copied then? This would give a first hint as to where to look for the cause.

Comment: @ljacqu Yes, I even tried doing so. I turned off the javascript from my browser and still i cannot select and copy the contents from my website.